# Verb order in a sentence

Tags: word-order, subordinate-clause

I’m currently studying German and ran across this sentence:

> Wer nicht zu Fuß gehen will, nimmt die U-Bahn.

It had been brought to my attention many many times that the verb should always be the second part in a sentence, even if the first part is not the subject of a sentence.
By that logic, shouldn’t the sentence be *Wer will nicht zu Fuß gehen, nimmt die U-Bahn*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to add to this, if the subordinate clause has one of the following words, the verb will remain as usual because they take up 0 (null) position:

> U - und
>   S - sondern
>   A - aber
>   D - denn
>   O - oder

For example:

> Ich bin gerade im Unterricht, **aber** ich **schreibe** hier.

But:

> Ich lerne Deutsch, **weil** ich es schön **finde**.

Comment: This does not answer the question; it should possibly have been a comment. However, it’s also factually wrong: *… aber ich schreibe hier* is a second main clause, not a subordinate clause.

Comment: I've tried to write it as a comment, but it does not let me yet.

Comment: So, "Ich bin gerade im Unterricht, aber schreibe ich hier" is not acceptable?

Comment: No, because there 'aber' is at position #0 and 'schreibe' at #1.

Answer (score 6):

The rule stating that the verb is put in second position applies to main clauses. For subordinate clauses, however, there is a different rule: The verb is generally in the *final* position, just as in your example.

Comment: Now I see the point, so I also ran into this sentence: "Kurz, man darf machen, was erlaubt ist, und nicht machen, was verboten ist"

If I decided to swap "darf" and "man" so it reads: "Kurz, **darf man** machen, was erlaubt ist, und nicht machen, was verboten ist." Would that be wrong?

Comment: @user268569 That’s almost a different question but here’s your answer: As you wrote it with a comma it would turn *darf man machen* into a question. If you left out the comma it would mean *one can do for a short or limited time.* The *kurz* seems to be some kind of drastically reduced other thing that does not occupy any position in the sentence when separated with a comma. I don’t know the grammatical name.

Comment: It's good you mentioned that _Kurz_ takes up null position, that would explain why one shouldn't use verb right after that.
Thanks a lot